# computing total price of shopping cart invoice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopping-cart, invoice

In my code after users choose products and go to cart page, my cart page creates an html structure like this for  all  total prices of selected products:
below here x indicates a number which is id of good that I fetch from Session, so every time these differ, also the number of fields changes  every time based on user's choice

```
<span class="total-x"> some value</span>
<span class="total-x"> some value</span>
<span class="total-x"> some value</span>
.
.
.
.
<span class="total-x"> some value</span>
```

for example if  cart gets id=3 form session after some other codes, page creates a field like this:

```
 <span class="total-3"> some value [has been computed]</span>
```

I want to sum up value of those field and put in a field like this:

```
<span id=total-all> </span>
```

I ask for every which would lead me to over come this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `start with selector` to identify that unknown class,

```
$("#total-all").text($("span[class^='total-']").get().reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + (+$(b).text());
},0));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xx4h08qs/)

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Glad to help! If this answer really helped you then try to click over that tick mark present with this answer. That will help future visitors to know this answer has worked for you.!!!

Comment: @Rajapraprabhu Aravindasamy, I tried to do that but Stackoverflow alerts that I need reputation at leas 15 to vote !

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Nope you can press the tick mark. Not the votes. :) You don't need any reputations or privileges to do that.

Comment: Yeah! I got it, going to become pro ... ;)

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Give the sample of that number here. If it has a space with it then try to use `return a + $.trim((+$(b).text()));`

Comment: no thanks that was a problem with my code I was using toLocalString function in order to show my numbers in money format which had conflict with your given code, thanks for your concern